# How do I view large typescript types in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a large type like this one:

```
type Large = {
    foo: 123,
    bar: 123,
    baz: 123
} | {
    foo: 123,
    bar: 123,
    baz: 123
} | {
    foo: 123,
    bar: 123,
    baz: 123
} | {
    foo: 123,
    bar: 123,
    baz: 123
} | {
    foo: 123,
    bar: 123,
    baz: 123
} | {
    foo: 123,
    bar: 123,
    baz: 123
} | {
    foo: 123,
    bar: 123,
    baz: 123
} | {
    foo: 123,
    bar: 123,
    baz: 123
} | {
    foo: 123,
    bar: 123,
    baz: 123
}
```

And this is how it gets shortened in VSCode when hovered:

[image]

How do I view the hidden part? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S. Of course the type I am trying to view is not that simple and it's not statically written as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a seemingly unrelated compiler setting called `noErrorTruncation`. It controls if types are truncated in errors. If you set this compiler option to `true` it will also prevent type truncation in tooltips.

**Note** This will prevent truncation of types (the `...` part) it will not unfortunately force the expansion of mapped or conditional types.

Comment: I have the feeling there is still a limit around 1600 characters. Tried on a few very long objects, and each time there's an ellipsis at the end, the text is truncated between 1600 and 1700 characters.